# Displaying two SQL tables in Razor Page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, html-table

I am trying to display two SQL tables on a single Razor page and struggling to get the code right. A single table is fine but when I try to add two the same data is being displayed in both tables.

Any help would be much appreciated.

This is the code I'm using:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebStoreTest.Pages

{
public class FreezerModel : PageModel
{
    public List<FreezerInfo> listFreezer = new List<FreezerInfo>();

    public void OnGet()
    {
        try
        {
   




            string connectionString = "Data Source=LAPTOP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
Catalog=test;user id=sa;password=****;";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM TopStock";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            FreezerInfo TopStock = new FreezerInfo();
                            TopStock.id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                            TopStock.Description = reader.GetString(1);
                            TopStock.Quantity = reader.GetString(2);



                            listFreezer.Add(TopStock);

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}

public class FreezerInfo
{
    public int id;
    public string Description;
    public string Quantity;
 }

}


public class FreezerModel : PageModel
{
public List<FreezerInfo> listFreezer = new List<FreezerInfo>();

public void OnGet()
{
    try
    {
        
        string connectionString = "Data Source=LAPTOP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
Catalog=test;user id=sa;password=****;";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM BottomStock";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        FreezerInfo BottomStock = new FreezerInfo();
                        BottomStock.Description = reader.GetString(1);
                        BottomStock.Quantity = reader.GetString(2);



                        listFreezer.Add(BottomStock);

                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
}

public class FreezerInfo
{
public int id;
public string Description;
public string Quantity;
}
```

And the page:

```
@page
@model WebStoreTest.Pages.FreezerModel
@{
}


<br />
<h2>Top Freezer Stock</h2>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }

    table {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

        table th {
            background-color: #B8DBFD;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        table th, table td {
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        table, table table td {
            border: 0px solid #ccc;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
       </tr>
     

    @foreach (var TopStock in Model.listFreezer)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@TopStock.Description</td>
            <td>@TopStock.Quantity</td>
         </tr>
    }
    
</table>

<table class="table">

    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>


    @foreach (var BottomStock in Model.listFreezer)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@BottomStock.Description</td>
            <td>@BottomStock.Quantity</td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just using one list and to model, which will mix your Freezers, pages etc.

Try to create 1 model class for the page. Create 2 lists in this model, and name them accordingly:

Like this:

```
public List<FreezerInfo> listTopFreezer = new List<FreezerInfo>();
public List<FreezerInfo> listBottomFreezer = new List<FreezerInfo>();
```

Fill them in your OnGet method:

```
public void OnGet()
{
   //fill listTopFreezer
   //fill listBottomFreezer
}
```

Then, make sure you use them while rendering the page:

```
@foreach (var TopStock in Model.listTopFreezer)
```

and

```
@foreach (var BottomStock in Model.listBottomFreezer)
```

---

By the way: your code suggest you put value in the naming of the iterator variable, such as in the naming in the `foreach` loops. It does not do anything; for all it matter you can name it like this:

```
@foreach (var foobar in Model.listFreezer)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Ok, I understand the part about creating two lists but I'm still struggling to put it all together.  Do I still double up on the code so that it reads both tables?

Comment: NOt sure what you mean with "double up" , but you need to create one model, with 2 properties (lists) for the 2 tables. Fill those lists in 1 method `OnGet` and display them in the blazor.